# How to use the date_select and time_select in the form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `Date` and `Time` column separately in the table in my database. When i click the Edit in the table, the `Date` and `Time` should display the values by `params`. The User can change the `Date` and the `Time` and update the `form`.

I tried the following:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Sent_Date, 'Sent Date:' %>
  <%= date_select(:Appointment_Date, object: f.object) %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Appointment_Time, 'Appointment Time:' %>
  <%= f.time_select(:history, :Appointment_Time, include_seconds: true) %>
</div>
```

It's not display the values correctly and it doesn't change to next record. It display to select the value. Do I need to convert the date here? Because, In the Database, its just the value like `2013/05/13` and in the field its like `20 December 2013`

`Time` field is not working. Please suggest me how to get solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using constants for your form fields?

Comment: No. I just tried... No reason. Thanks

Comment: Then don't. Constants (every variable beginning with a capital letter) are value stores that you don't want to change. Rails will let you change them, but will give you a warning each time - and it doesn't make sense for you, since these are fields that you want to be editable.

Comment: I felt like adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use constants as fields for your model. Any variable starting with a capital letter will be treated like a constant, and constants are meant not to change. Ruby will give you a `warning: already initialized constant` when trying to change a constant's value, so that might be the reason you can't change the time and date.